# How to return customized JSON response for an error in graphene / django-graphene?

Tags: graphene-python

I want to add status field to error response, so instead of this:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Authentication credentials were not provided",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "viewer": null
  }
}
```

It should be like this:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 401,  # or 400 or 403 or whatever error status suits
      "message": "Authentication credentials were not provided",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "viewer": null
  }
}
```

I found out that I only can change message by raising Exception inside resolver: `raise Error('custom error message')`, but how to add field?

Code example:

```
class Query(UsersQuery, graphene.ObjectType):
    me = graphene.Field(SelfUserNode)

    def resolve_me(self, info: ResolveInfo):
        user = info.context.user
        if not user.is_authenticated:
            # but status attr doesn't exist...
            raise GraphQLError('Authentication credentials were not provided', status=401)  
        return user
```

Comment: can you provide some code, is this a mutation?

Comment: @MauricioCortazar, added

Answer (score 11):

Update the default `GraphQLView` with the following:

```py
from graphene_django.views import GraphQLView as BaseGraphQLView


class GraphQLView(BaseGraphQLView):

    @staticmethod
    def format_error(error):
        formatted_error = super(GraphQLView, GraphQLView).format_error(error)

        try:
            formatted_error['context'] = error.original_error.context
        except AttributeError:
            pass

        return formatted_error


urlpatterns = [
    path('api', GraphQLView.as_view()),
]
```

This will look for the `context` attribute in any exceptions raised. If it exists, it'll populate the error with this data.

Now you can create exceptions for different use cases that populate the `context` attribute. In this case you want to add the status code to errors, here's an example of how you'd do that:

```py
class APIException(Exception):

    def __init__(self, message, status=None):
        self.context = {}
        if status:
            self.context['status'] = status
        super().__init__(message)
```

You'd use it like this:

```py
raise APIException('Something went wrong', status=400)
```

Comment: I don't think this is working anymore with the latest django_graphene version

Answer (score 1):

I didn't found a way to solve your problem int the way that you propose, otherwise i extend the `LoginRequiredMixin` class like this:

```
class LoginRequiredMixin:
    def dispatch(self, info, *args, **kwargs):
        if not info.user.is_authenticated:
            e =  HttpError(HttpResponse(status=401, content_type='application/json'), 'Please log in first')
            response = e.response
            response.content = self.json_encode(info, [{'errors': [self.format_error(e)]}])
            return response

            return super().dispatch(info, *args, **kwargs)

class PrivateGraphQLView(LoginRequiredMixin, GraphQLView):
    schema=schema
```

and in your url:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from educor.schema import PrivateGraphQLView
url(r'^graphql', csrf_exempt(PrivateGraphQLView.as_view(batch=True)))
```

you can't see the status with the graphiql but in your client you can get it in the headers or you could modify this line to add in the response `response.content = self.json_encode(info, [{'errors': [self.format_error(e)]}])`
. Hope it helps anyway i'll leave you another possible solution https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/issues/252

Comment: As far as I know (now) root `error` field is for server error and I need to introduce custom `error` field inside `data`. But it is not best practice, it's still opened question for graphql community how to handle user errors. Right now I just add additional fields inside `data`: success, status, errors. 

And also by specification graphql server should return only 500 and 200 status codes, so I can't accept your answer ):

Comment: @Aiven i know, as I said I didn't found the so I don't expect to you accept the answer, but I leave you this solution that might work for you, I will add to favourite if someone can answer it